Gesture events propogation in Flutter
A map application, having flutter_map and a search bar with static search results.

Problem: When I drag inside the text input or the container showing the results, the drag is working on the map. Click event is also not happening inside the container, only on the map.
Need a solution for this.
I have seen solutions like GestureDetector/AbsorbPointer and tried them. But none works.
There is a widget called map_widget which essentially imports and displays all the items other than the map, like home icon, people icon, location icon and the search component. Search component is called search_widget.
